# Generate a random number which fulfills some conditions

Tags: java, random

I want to generate a random number which shouldn't be greater than variable 'max' and fulfills the condition below:

```
    int fi= 17;
    int max=96;
    int i=1;
    int rez=0;
    while(i<max) 
    {
        if((i*max)%fi==1) rez=i;
         i++;
    }
    System.out.println(rez);
```

The result is always 0.What is wrong?

Comment: What condition? What is the result?

Comment: The condition is `if((i*rand)%fi==1) ` . The problem is I get 0 every time.

Comment: Declaration of rand is missing in your example. Can you post the complete code?

Comment: The result of `(i*rand)%fi` is zero for any `i` if `rand` is a multiple of `fi`.

Comment: Sorry it was a misstake, it should be `if((i*max)%fi==1)`

Comment: where is the random number then? You need a `rand()` somewhere

Comment: I set i as a random number. While Iterates i checks if i fulfills the condition .

Comment: As written by @Harshit your pool of "random" number is `14, 31, 48, 65, 82`. Is this really what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

```
    import java.util.*;
 class hello
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
    Random r=new Random();
    int i=1;
    while(i<96)
    {

      if(((i*96)%17)==1)
      { 
        System.out.println("i:- "+i);
     }
     i++;
   }
 }
}
```

Output:
i:- 14
i:- 31
i:- 48
i:- 65
i:- 82

Comment: Whyt's the use of `Random r`?

Answer (score 0):

I launched your program modified using max instead of rand as you wrote and adding some printf inside loop. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int fi= 17;
    int max=96;
    int i=0;
    int rez=0;
    while(i<max) 
    {
        printf("\n%i", (i*max)%fi);

        if((i*max)%fi==1)
        {
            rez=i;
            printf(" -> %i", rez);
        }
         i++;
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("\nFinal result: %i", rez);
    printf("\n");
}
```

And here's the output:

```
0
11
5
16
10
4
15
9
3
14
8
2
13
7
1 -> 14
12
6
0
11
5
16
10
4
15
9
3
14
8
2
13
7
1 -> 31
12
6
0
11
5
16
10
4
15
9
3
14
8
2
13
7
1 -> 48
12
6
0
11
5
16
10
4
15
9
3
14
8
2
13
7
1 -> 65
12
6
0
11
5
16
10
4
15
9
3
14
8
2
13
7
1 -> 82
12
6
0
11
5
16
10
4
15
9
3
14
8

Final result: 82
```

I don't get always 0 as you say. Where do you get 0?